# allow maximum 2 digits at any place within alphanumeric characters javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a user string in js where user is allowed to input alphanumeric characters with some restrictions. Restriction is that ,within that alphanumeric characters, user is only allowed to use 2 digits(same or different)at any place within the alphanumeric range. 
Few examples are:

`1aabdjc2jfd`

`1klajdfjkladf2`

`35klfjaddf`

`fadsfadsf23`

`fadf2lkdjaf3fdf`

`dfdf1kjdkf1` and so on

Any idea how this can be done with JS Regex ??

Comment: Wait, so a string with two numbers is ok? which strings are pass/fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're looking for is an alphabetic string with up to two digits somewhere in there.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*(?:\d[a-zA-Z]*){0,2}$/
```

The first `[a-zA-Z]*` matches the initial alphabetic part (if any).

`\d[a-zA-Z]*` matches a digit, followed by 0 or more alphabetic characters. Wrapping this in `{0,2}` is what allows up to two digits total.

If it's not up to two digits but *exactly two* digits you're looking for, just replace `{0,2}` by `{2}`:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*(?:\d[a-zA-Z]*){2}$/
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to find out exactly how much digits the string contains:

```js
var regex = /\d/g;

function valid(string) {
  return string.match(regex).length <= 2;
}

var strings = [
  '1aabdjc2jfd',
  '1klajdfjkladf2',
  '35klfjaddf',
  'fadsfadsf23',
  'fadf2lkdjaf3fdf',
  'dfdf1kjdkf1',
  'dfd2f1kjdk1f1',
  'df21212d2f1kjdk1f1',
  'dfd2f1kjdk434341f1'
];

strings.forEach(str => console.log(str, valid(str)));
```

Answer (score 0):

One option here is to just use a negative lookahead assertion, which checks if *three* or more digits occur adjacent to each other.  Here is the pattern I suggest:

```
^(?!.*[0-9]{3,})[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Code sample:

```js
console.log(/^(?!.*[0-9]{3,})[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test('1klajdfjkladf2'));
console.log(/^(?!.*[0-9]{3,})[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test('1klajdfjkladf2333'));
```

If I misunderstood your requirement, and instead you to check that *only* two numbers occur, when numbers occur at all, then there is a much simpler pattern:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]*(?:[0-9]{2})?)*$
```

### Demo